# Add style to pure VUE component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have a `Element.js` file, which is a VUE component exported like this:

```
export default {
  template: `
    <div>
     <h1>Single-file JavaScript Component</h1>
     <p>{{ message }}</p>
    </div>
  `,
  data() {
    return {
      message: 'Oh hai from the component'
    }
  },
  style: `
    h1, p {
        color: red !important; /* NOT WORKING */
    }
  `
}
```

And not in the usual `<template></template> <script></script> <style></style>` [dot]Vue structure.

Using the first structure. **Is it possible to add CSS style to it?**

I tried with the `style` prop as shown above but it is not working.

Answer (score 4):

As the [The Single File Components](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/single-file-components.html) documentation is stating you can't do it via CSS

> **No CSS support** means that while HTML and JavaScript are modularized into components, CSS is conspicuously left out

But you can still use [Binding-Inline-Styles](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html#Binding-Inline-Styles) to style your component.

```js
Vue.component('button-counter', {
  template: `
    <div>
     <h1 :style="style">Single-file JavaScript Component</h1>
     <p :style="style">{{ message }}</p>
    </div>
  `,
  data() {
    return {
      message: 'Oh hai from the component',
      style: {
        color: 'red'
      }
    }
  }
})
new Vue({ el: '#components-demo' })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.16/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="components-demo">
  <button-counter></button-counter>
</div>
```